# Getting Correlation failed exception while signing in the auth0 inside an iframe

Tags: iframe, openid-connect, auth0

I can successfully login with the standalone mvc app without the `iframe`. But when I put the same app inside an `iframe`, I'm getting the `Exception: Correlation failed` exception.

[image]

When I tried with `postman`, I'm getting the following response:

[image]

I have also tried with different `SameSiteMode` configurations but to no avail. Is there any  way or workaround to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the cookie is not sent by the browser.

You need to use HTTPS to get it to work together with samesite=none;Secure attributes added to the cookie. Otherwise the cookie will be blocked by the browser.

You can diagnose why a cookie was not accepted or used by going to the Chrome devtools and:

1. Open the Browser Developer Tools (F12)
2. Click on the network tab and reload the page
3. Click on the Cookies request
4. Select the Cookies tab
5. Then hover your mouse over the (i) to see the reasoning by the browser

[image]

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)